# Prove that any central function of $\mathrm{SU}_{2}$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to the following subgroup.

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, physics, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups

The question is given below:

> 3. Prove that any central functon $f$ on $\mathrm{SU}_2$ is uniquely determined by its restriction to the subgroup
>    $$
>      \mathbf{T}
>      =
>      \biggl\{
>        A(z) = \begin{pmatrix} z & 0 \\ 0 & z^{-1} \end{pmatrix}
>        \,\Bigg|\,
>        z ∈ \mathbf{C}, |z| = 1
>      \biggr\} \,,
>    $$
>    and that $f(A(z)) = f(A(z^{-1}))$.
>
> ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P166K.png))

But I do not know how to solve it, could anyone give me a hint please?

**EDIT:**

> **Definition.**
> A function $f$ on the group $G$ with the property that
> $$
>   f(g x g^{-1}) = f(x) \qquad \text{for all $g, x ∈ G$}
> $$
> is called a *central function*.
>
> ([Original scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4wZD.png))

Comment: what is your definition for "central function"?

Comment: okay I will edit my question to include the definition.@PinkPanther

Comment: Consider the fact that any matrix $A\in SU(2)$ can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}z & -\overline w \\ w & \overline z\end{pmatrix}$ for some $w,z\in\mathbb C$ with $|w|^2+|z|^2=1$ and that every matrix of this form is diagonalizable, that is, there exists $B\in SO(2)$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.
The $f(A(z))=f(A(z^{-1})$ part will then follow from $A(z^{-1})=A(\overline z)=BA(z)B^{-1}$, where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: and why the determination is unique? also the first equality in the last line follows from the fact that A is unitary? and why in the second equality there is no baar on z? @PinkPanther

Comment: yes, unitary is crucial here. Since $SU(2)$ is a group, $BAB^{-1}$ is again in $SU(2) $ and any diagonal matrix in $SU(2)$ is of the form $A(z)$ for some $z$ with $|z|=1$.

Comment: And from where the uniqueness come?@PinkPanther

Comment: Do you mean $B \in SO(3)$ not $SO_{2}$?@PinkPanther

Comment: How can I restrict any central function to the subgroup given above? what does it mean?@PinkPanther

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *What does it mean to restrict a function: For a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$, the restriction of $f$ to a subset $U\subset X$ is a function $g:U\rightarrow Y$ such that $g(u)=f(u)$ for all $u\in U$. Extending $g$ to $X$ means that we construct a new function $g':X\rightarrow Y$ such that $g'(u)=g(u)$ for all $u\in U$.*

Now back to the initial problem:

> **Remark:** Any matrix $A\in SU(2)$ can be written as $\begin{pmatrix}z & -\overline w \\ w & \overline z\end{pmatrix}$ for some $w,z\in\mathbb C$ with $|w|^2+|z|^2=1$.
>   Moreover, every matrix of this form is diagonalizable, that is, there exists $B\in SU(2)$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is a diagonal matrix.

The $f(A(z))=f(A(z^{-1}))$ part follows from $A(z^{-1})=BA(z)B^{-1}$, where $B=\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$.

**Uniqueness**: If $f$ is a central function and $A\in SU(2)$, then
$$f(A)=f(BAB^{-1})$$
where $B\in SU(2)$ such that $BAB^{-1}$ is diagonal.

> **Claim:** For any matrix $C\in SU(2)$, $CAC^{-1}=A(z)$ is diagonal if and only if $C=B$ or $C=B^{-1}$, where $B$ is as in the remark.

The eigenvalues of a matrix do not change under unitary change of basis, and since $BAB^{-1}$ has eigenvalues $z$ and $\overline z$ (because diagonal), $A$ has the same eigenvalues. Hence $CAC^{-1}$ is diagonal if and only if $CAC^{-1}=A(z)$ or $A(z^{-1})$.
But this is equivalent to $C=B$ or $C=B^{-1}$.

Comment: I am studying from a book called " Linear representations of groups " for Ernest B. Vinberg and the book did not mention any relation between $SO_{2}$ and $SU_{2}$? could you please tell me the relation?

Comment: @Smart $SO(2)$ is the group of all _orthogonal_ matrices with **real** entries, i.e. all matrices $A\in\mathbb R^{2\times 2}$ such that $AA^\top=I$ and $\det A=1$. 
SU(2)$ is the group of _unitary_ matrices with **complex**, i.e. all matrices $A\in\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ such that $AA^\dagger=I$ and $\det A=1$, where $I$ denotes the identity matrix and $A^\dagger$ denotes the complex conjugate transpose.

Comment: In particular $SO(2)$ is a proper subgroup of $SU(2)$. @Smart

Comment: why $A(z^{-1}) = A(\bar{z} )$?

Comment: @Smart You are right, this is not correct. In my head it was like $|z|^2=z\overline z$ and then something...
But it is not relevant for the argument, so i will edit that.

Comment: The B cannot be complex because "A rotation by an angle not a multiple of $\pi$ is a real member of $SU(2)$ with non-real eigenvalues, and therefore the $B$ can't be real."

Comment: @Smart no wait, it is correct that if $|z|=1$ then $z^{-1}=\overline z$, because 
$$z^{-1}=1/z=\frac{\overline z}{z\overline z}=\frac{\overline z}{|z|^2}=\overline z$$
And yes, I meant to write $B\in SU(2)$, I guess I made a typo there...

Comment: How did you find the matrix $B$?

Comment: this B will not give me A upon computing B^{-1}AB

Comment: @Smart Yes, for $A(z)$ it will give you $A(z^{-1})$.

Comment: Actually $A$ is diagonalized matrix by its definition and the $B$ will be either the identity matrix or any diagonalized matrix.

Comment: hence the uniqueness proof that you provide here is not applicable

Comment: @Smart I do not understand what you are talking about

Comment: just look at the matrix in the question thoroughly ...... it is diagonal matrix

Comment: how did you find the matrix B?

Comment: @Smart you have to extend the function on all of $SU(2)$, given that you know the function on the subgroup $T$, and preserve the central property. 
And you have to show that this can be done in a unique way. 
So you have to look at arbitrary matrices in $SU(2)$, which need not be diagonal. 
Diagonal matrices in $SU(2)$ are always of the form $A(z)$ for some $z\in S^1$

Comment: if A is diagonalizable then A should be similar to a diagonal matrix, so in your definition for diagonalizable it is not the same A both on the left and right side of the equal sign.

Comment: That is correct, I was using the $A(z)$ notation from your question for appropriate $z$. @smart

Comment: $BAB^{-1}$ do not have eigenvalues $\omega$ and $\bar{\omega}$

Comment: Might I ask from which book these excerpts were taken? The reason I ask is that I wanted to know what is the name of a function obeying $f(x)=f(gxg^{-1})$ and dreamt up the idea that it might be called 'central'. So I managed to hit the nail on the head---but I could do with a reference. Tx