# Show that the characters of the representations $\phi_{n}$ of $SU(2)$ constitute a complete orthogonal set.

Tags: proof-verification, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, characters

The question is given below:

> [image]

And the other questions mentioned are (I know the solutions of all of them):

> [image]
>
> [image]

**Sorry for the bad formulation of the my question at the first time I have edited it**

I think I should use this theorem in the proof of the first part:

> [image]
>
> [image]

As I know that $SU_{2}$ is a compact topological group and I know that $\Phi_{n}$ is a series of irreducible complex representation of $SU_{2}$ then their matrix elements form a complete orthogonal set in the space $C_{2}(SU_{2})$ by the theorem where $C_{2}(X)$ denote infinite dimensional hermitian space. **My problem is that the question requires the complete orthonormal set in the space of continuous central functions on SU_{2}** , could anyone help me in showing this please?

Also for the second part of the question I do not know how to show it from the following givens (especially the three problems the author require me to used), could anyone help me please in this part?

Comment: What is 7.4? which book is this from?

Comment: Ernest B. Vinberg ..... "Linear representations of groups "@Sheve

Comment: @Sheve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166964/question-4-chapter-iii-section-7-in-vinberg-linear-representations-of-groups

Comment: @Sheve and this is a solution ofanother  one problem of the problems mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3168577/prove-that-the-linear-span-of-some-functions-coincide-with-the-space-of-the-foll

Comment: And this is a discussion of a solution of one of the problems mentioned https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166437/prove-that-any-central-function-of-su-2-is-uniquely-determined-by-its-restri?rq=1   I hope you have time to help me in  question 7 @Sheve

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3178900/a-discrepancy-in-understanding-a-solution-given-to-me-here-for-a-problem-of-vinb @stefanDawydiak

Comment: Orthogonal for which inner product ? The inner product is the one coming from the Haar measure. The group is compact (and the representations are unitary) so if two characters are not orthogonal they have a subrepresentation in common (look at $g \cdot v= \int_G \pi(x) \rho(gx^{-1})v dx$)

Comment: could you tell me a little more details please?@reuns

Comment: @reuns  I have edited my question .... could you please check it now if you have time? thanks

Comment: @Sheve I have edited my question ..... could you please check it now?

Comment: Since the central functions is a subspace of all functions, you just need to show that these function are central.

Comment: * this follows immediately since all trace functions (characters) are central

Comment: @Sheve are the central functions hermitian?

Comment: @Sheve what about the second part of the question?

Comment: @Sheve are the central functions hermitian? or shall I use that functions in $C[G]$ is a dense subspace of $C_{2} (G)$ which is a consequence of Weierstrass's theorem?